# Nano in AWS Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nano

My 'vi' editor skills are rusty so I thought I would use Nano on my Linux 2 Ec2 instance. The legend at the bottom surely helps, but I can not figure out what the 'M-" means. Such as 'M-Undo', 'M-E Redo' and 'M-A Mark Text'.  I now realize that the 'alt' key can be used but what is the 'M' trying to tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Just for my education.  Why is my question above voted down?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nano docs explains what `M-` is:

> Meta-key sequences are notated with 'M-' and can
> be entered using either the Alt, Cmd, or Esc key, depending on your
> keyboard setup.

`M-` just denotes activation key, which can be `Alt`, `Cm`d, or `Esc`.